# How to change value in random element of array in JSON in MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a JSON structure like this:

```
{

"details": {
  "product_name": "Example Product",
  "description": "This is an example product",
  "price": 10.99,
  "dimensions": {
    "width": 10,
    "height": 15,
    "depth": 5
  },
  "reviews": [
    {
      "author": "John Smith",
      "rating": 4,
      "comment": "Great product, would buy again"
    },
    {
      "author": "Jane Doe",
      "rating": 3,
      "comment": "Product was okay, not great"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

I need somehow change value of field 'author' in array 'reviews' that has 'rating' equals to 3.

I've tried something like this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET json_data = JSON_REPLACE(json_data, 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
        REPLACE(
            JSON_SEARCH(json_data, 'one', 3, NULL, '$.details.reviews[*].rating'), 
            '.rating', '.author'
        )
    ),
    'New Author'
)
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_data, 'one', 3, NULL, '$.details.reviews[*].rating') IS NOT NULL;
```

but it did not work.

Please explain what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON_SEARCH` function works with only string scalars as mentioned in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html), so your numbers must surrounded by quotes.

To make it work we first need to add quotes to numbers using `REGEXP_REPLACE` as follows :

```
select json_data, REGEXP_REPLACE(json_data, '(:\\s*)(\\d+\\.?\\d*)', '$1"$2"')
from my_table;
```

Will Return valid json for `JSON_SEARCH`:

```
{"details": {"price": "10.99", "reviews": [{"author": "John Smith", "rating": "4", "comment": "Great product, would buy again"}, {"author": "Jane Doe", "rating": "3", "comment": "Product was okay, not great"}], "dimensions": {"depth": "5", "width": "10", "height": "15"}, "description": "This is an example product", "product_name": "Example Product"}}
```

So your query can be :

```
select json_data, REGEXP_REPLACE(json_data, '(:\\s*)(\\d+\\.?\\d*)', '$1"$2"')
```

from my_table;

```
UPDATE my_table SET json_data = JSON_REPLACE(json_data, 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
        REPLACE(
            JSON_SEARCH(REGEXP_REPLACE(json_data, '(:\\s*)(\\d+\\.?\\d*)', '$1"$2"'), 'one', 3, NULL, '$.details.reviews[*].rating'), 
            '.rating', '.author'
        )
    ),
    'New Author'
)
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(REGEXP_REPLACE(json_data, '(:\\s*)(\\d+\\.?\\d*)', '$1"$2"'), 'one', 3, NULL, '$.details.reviews[*].rating') IS NOT NULL;
```

Result :

```
{"details": {"price": 10.99, "reviews": [{"author": "John Smith", "rating": 4, "comment": "Great product, would buy again"}, {"author": "New Author", "rating": 3, "comment": "Product was okay, not great"}], "dimensions": {"depth": 5, "width": 10, "height": 15}, "description": "This is an example product", "product_name": "Example Product"}}
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C16GS35Vv4MSSVjdrqssQ/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tried your request - got [22001][3141] Data truncation: Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_search: "Invalid value." at position 59.

Comment: If you are testing using different Json can you share it here ?

Comment: There was an issue on regex and fixed it. I have made an update to add quotes to only numeric values that comes after *:*, can you recheck